# Why does my iphone provisioning profile not show up on Organizer?

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning

I've followed the iphone provisioning assistant to step 3 where I'm supposed to see my installed iphone provisioning profile under provisioning on the Organizer. I currently am unable to see that. I've tried the following guide too.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html

Under "Provisioning Profiles" I can see both my originally created & installed profile whilst following the assistant and the generic "Team Provisioning Profile". However under "Included Devices, my iphone's "Installed" status is blank. Does anyone know why does my provisioning profile not show up on under "Provisioning" on my iphone's Summary tab when both guides say that the profile should automatically be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dragging/dropping the provisioning profiles into the Organizer, did you sync your device using iTunes so it will install them onto it?

Answer (score 0):

Check in Settings>General>Profiles if its there.

Also try restarting the iphone provisioning assistant.